Can't pip install requirements in Python3.12 venv on macOS
Trying to set up a Python3.12 (installed via Homebrew) venv on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 but completely unable to use pip.
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python3 -m ensurepip
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

Always results in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'"
It's very confusing, I thought pip came with Python already? And the python3 -m ensurepip results in: "Successfully installed pip-24.2". I've tried all combinations of python/python3 pip/pip3. I also tried python3 -m install numpy (just one package) with the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Try cleaning up: rm -rf .venv, then retry the steps, same error?

Or python3 -m venv .venv --clear, will also delete .venv before creating the virtual environment.

@hoefling same results, unfortunately

Solved this by naming the virtual environment "venv" and NOT ".venv". I guess there's some conflict naming an environment ".venv" that doesn't exist in Linux?

"I guess there's some conflict naming an environment ".venv" that doesn't exist in Linux?" Not at all. I regularly use names .venv, venv, somename-venv, whatever, never had any problem with .venv.

Just tested: python3.12 -m venv .venv && . .venv/bin/activate && pip --version, the output is "pip 24.2 from /home/phd/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)". No problem.

The source command worked, then the folder name isn't the issue
